# Unable to style UL containing DIV's

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I'm trying to style a `UL` horizontally but my code will only work when I remove the two imbedded `DIV's`.

If i remove the `div = thumb` and the `div = button` the list styles correctly.

Has anyone got any ideas how I can fix this?

HTML / PHP:

```
    <div class="container-app" id="container-app">

    <?php if(isset($events)) { ?> 

            <div>

                <div class="header-text">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 30px;"></h1>
                </div>

                <ul class="events">

                    <?php  foreach ($events as $images){ ?>
                        <li>

                            <div class="thumb">
                                <?php $eventURL = base_url('eventguide/event/id/') . '/'. $images->id; ?>

                                    <a class="open-event" href="<?php echo $eventURL; ?>">
                                        <img src="<?php echo base_url() .  $images->image_link ?>" width = '165' height ='230'>
                                    </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="button">

                                <a class="open-event" id="pbutton" href="<?php echo $eventURL; ?>">
                                    <b><?php echo date("D jS M", strtotime($images->event_date)); ?></b>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>

                </ul>

            </div>
        <?php  } ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container-app ul
{
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#container-app ul li { display: inline; }

#container-app ul li .thumb .open-event { display: inline; }

#container-app ul li .thumb .button { display: inline; }

#container-app ul li a
{
  color:#329AF2;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#container-app ul li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that can be improved here.

First of all **img** and **a** html elements are inline by default so there shouldn't be a need to include the .thumb and .button **divs** (which are block by default).

Secondly, the line: #container-app ul li .thumb .button { display: inline; }
is incorrect as according to your html .thumb and .button are siblings where as the css above states that .button is *inside* of .thumb.

The whole thing can be simplified.

In your css, Remove the #container-app ul and replace it with;

```
.events {margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; text-align:center; }
```

Then alter the rest of your css like so:

```
.events li {display:inline-block; }
.events .button { color:#329AF2; text-decoration:none; font-weight: bold; }
.events .button:hover { color:#fff; background-color:#369; }
```

.events .button {... } could be replaced with .events-button { /*button styles go here*/ } and you could change .thumb to .events-thumb (you'd need to add the classes to the corresponding a tags in your html).

This would be re-written in your css as;

```
.events { ... }
.events li { ... }
.events-thumb { /* add a margin to space out the image from the button */ }
.events-button { /* styles from .style a go here*/ }
.events-button:hover { ... }
```

The new css above will perform better too as the browser will only be looking for an element with a class of events rather than a ul that is nested somewhere inside an element with an id of container-app (CSS reads right to left)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `display: inline` on `#container-app ul`, and changing `display: inline` in `#container-app ul li` to `display: inline-block`.